# How to create a git backup on a repo that's using lfs?

Tags: git, bitbucket, backup, backup-strategies

Trying to set up a backup strategy to have rolling backup of multiple git repos and from the research it seems that [git bundling](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling) is the most complete solution, but use case that I cannot find in the documentation is how does it handle git LFS.

Or are there other strategies being used for keeping backups of repos that use LFS

Comment: Looks like bundle support isn't coming anytime soon. Tar/Zip it up? https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1755